# Root Access to avast moble

Tags: applications

How do you grant root access to an anti virus program manually on a Samsung tablet.Because I want to enable a firewall to be more safe

Comment: How did you root your device? Most of the rooting methods would install an apk which would prompt a user whenever any app wants to gain root access.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install an app that manages root access for you such as SuperSu or Superuser. These apps give you various options for controlling root access for apps. These apps prompt you to ask whether you want to grant an app root access or not.

SuperSu: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu

SuperUser(by ChainsDD): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su